# CallWindowProc - strange behavior

Tags: c++, winapi, subclassing

It definetly works, but in a strange way.

I'm replacing RichEdit control's procedure with

```
    WNDPROC g_OrigREditText = 
(WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr( g_hwnd_RichEdit, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)REditWndProc);
```

Then, I SendMessage to RichEdit control using EM_REPLACESEL msg, and the text appears in the RichEdit control as it should. But when I replace standard procedure with my own, and process EM_REPLACESEL in mine own procedure, then the following scenario happens. Here's the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK REditWndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp )
{
    switch( msg )
    {

    case EM_REPLACESEL:
    {
        int sdfsdf = 0;

        CallWindowProc( (WNDPROC)g_OrigREditText, hwnd, msg, wp, lp );
        break;
    }


    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hwnd, msg, wp, lp);
        break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Ok, I send an EM_REPLACESEL message to the RichEdit as usual and it works well, cos I catch operation pointer in "case EM_REPLACESEL" block.

Then CallWindowProc should do its job by passing parameters to the next procedure in the chain, but instead nothing happens, the text doesn't appear in a RichEdit control. Looks like something prevent the message to be passed to old procedure, but! if I replace g_OrigREditText with REditWndProc, then I catch the same UINT msg again, so it definetely pass parameters further, like it should.

So what's wrong with CallWindowProc or with my code, where should I dig to fix the problem?

Comment: Return the value returned by `CallWindowProc`. Also, although not related to your problem, drop the unnecessary casting. And replace C style casts with C++ named casts.

Comment: You should call `CallWindowProc` on all routes, and there is no need to perform cast when calling it since `g_OrigREditText` is already of correct type.

Comment: Yeah, thanks alot, calling CallWindowProc on all routes fixed the problem. Odd casts are just the result of experiments with CWP)

Comment: This is not how you subclass controls. It is brittle, with lots of issues, that have been fixed in Windows XP (more than 15 years ago). See [Subclassing Controls Using ComCtl32.dll version 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx#subclassing_v6) to learn how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing is called "subclassing" and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570(v=vs.85).aspx#subclassing_window) can be useful .

usually there are more events that occurs in relating with one message so change your code to this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK REditWndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp )
{
    if( msg == EM_REPLACESEL)
    {
        // whatever you want
        return TRUE;// comment this 
                    // if you want to give it to the original proc.
    }

    return CallWindowProc( g_OrigREditText, hwnd, msg, wp, lp );
}
```